# Integrating with a multivariate Gaussian

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, integral

I need to figure out the steps to solve the following integral, where $Q(\mathbf{w})$ is a multivariate Gaussian with mean $\overline{\mathbf{w}}$ and covariance $\mathbf{C}$:

\begin{align}\int  Q(\mathbf{w}) \> \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{w}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} \> \mathrm{d} \mathbf{w} = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{CA}) + \frac{1}{2} \overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \overline{\mathbf{w}}
\end{align}

Essentially, I'm very happy to try and work it out for myself if someone can just point me to relevant textbooks/online info or give a hint - I'm just having trouble getting started.

So far I've tried making a substitution $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{w} - \overline{\mathbf{w}}$ which gets me to:

\begin{align}
\int  Q(\mathbf{w}) \> \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{w}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} \> \mathrm{d} \mathbf{w} &= \int  R(\mathbf{u}) \> \frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{u}+ \overline{\mathbf{w}})^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{u}+ \overline{\mathbf{w}}) \> \mathrm{d} \mathbf{u} \\
& = \int R(\mathbf{u}) \{ \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u} + \frac{1}{2} \overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}\overline{\mathbf{w}} + \frac{1}{2} \overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \overline{\mathbf{w}} \} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{u}
\end{align}

where $R(\mathbf{u})$ is a multivariate Gaussian with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and covariance $\mathbf{C}$. From here, I can see how the second term, $\frac{1}{2} \overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \overline{\mathbf{w}}$, might come out of this expression, but not at all how the first term, $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{CA})$ might come out.

I also had an idea to try a substitution of the form $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{M}^{-1}(\mathbf{w} - \overline{\mathbf{w}})$, where $\mathbf{MM}^\mathrm{T} = \mathbf{C}$.

I've also tried working in Einstein summation notation (as I thought this might make the origin of the trace more clear) but that didn't get me much farther.

Thanks!

Update:

Following a helpful comment by @whuber, I had a look at the one dimensional case in order to gain insight, using the equivalent one dimensional substitution to $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{M}^{-1}(\mathbf{w} - \overline{\mathbf{w}})$.

\begin{align}
 \int \frac{1}{2} w^2 a \> Q(w)\> \mathrm{d} w &= \int \frac{1}{2} w^2 a \> \frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{2c}(w-\overline{w})^2)}{(2\pi c)^{1/2}} \mathrm{d}w
\end{align}
Now we make a substitution of $y = \frac{1}{c^{1/2}} (w - \overline{w})$.
\begin{align}
 & = \int \frac{1}{2}  ( yc^{1/2} + \overline{w})^2  a \frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{2} y^2 )}{(2\pi)^{1/2} } \mathrm{d}y \\
  & = \int \frac{1}{2}  ( y^2c + 2yc^{1/2}\overline{w} + \overline{w}^2 )  a \> \frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{2} y^2 )}{(2\pi)^{1/2} } \mathrm{d} y \\
\end{align}
And we notice that the term with $2yc^{1/2}\overline{w}$ is odd, and that $\overline{w}^2$ is independent of $y$.
\begin{align}
 & =\frac{1}{2} \overline{w}^2 a +  \int \frac{1}{2} y^2c  a \> \frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{2} y^2 )}{(2\pi)^{1/2} } \mathrm{d} y \\
  & =\frac{1}{2} \overline{w}^2 a + \frac{1}{2} ca \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}  \int  y^2\> \exp(-\frac{1}{2} y^2 )  \mathrm{d} y
\end{align}
Finally, we integrate by parts, using $u = y$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} y} = y \exp(-\frac{1}{2} y^2)$.
\begin{align}
 \int \frac{1}{2} w^2 a \> Q(w)\> \mathrm{d} w  &= \frac{1}{2}\overline{w}^2 a + \frac{1}{2}ca
\end{align}

Comment: First principles tell you the answer will be a bilinear function of $C$ and $A$ and a quadratic function of $\bar w,$ so that gets you most of the way there while suggesting what change of variables to employ.  Your last idea of a substitution is a good one.  If you want to get some sense of what's involved, then first solve the special case where $CA$ is diagonal and $\bar w=0.$ If that's too hard, solve the one-dimensional version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The means and covariances already evaluate all the integrals you need, allowing this result to be obtained purely algebraically.**  It actually has nothing to do with Normal distributions (except insofar as they have finite covariances in the first place).

---

Let $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ be a multivariate random variable with mean vector $$\mu = (\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_n)=(E[X_1], E[X_2], \ldots, E[X_n])$$ and covariance matrix $$C = (c_{ij}) = (E[X_iX_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j]) = (E[X_iX_j]-\mu_i\mu_j),$$ which can be rewritten $$E[X_iX_j] = c_{ij} + \mu_i\mu_j.$$

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be any $n\times n$ matrix.  The definition of matrix multiplication, linearity of expectation, the foregoing formula, and definition of the trace imply

$$\eqalign{
E\left[X^\prime A X\right] &= E\left[\sum_{i,j} X_i a_{ij} X_j\right] \\
&= \sum_{ij} E[X_iX_j] a_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{ij}(C_{ij} +\mu_i\mu_j) a_{ij} \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(CA) + \mu^\prime A \mu.
}$$

Multiply everything by $1/2$ and let $X$ be multivariate normal.

Comment: BTW, using the Einstein summation convention permits you to remove all appearances of "$\sum_{ij}$" but otherwise wouldn't change any of this demonstration.

Comment: Thanks @whuber - does this mean that the final answer should be $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{CA}) + \frac{1}{2}\overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \overline{\mathbf{w}}$ instead of $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{CA}) + \frac{1}{2}\overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \overline{\mathbf{w}}$? The one dimensional case seems to agree with your answer, but the paper I am looking at (Barber & Bishop, 1998) gives $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{CA}) + \frac{1}{2}\overline{\mathbf{w}}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A} \overline{\mathbf{w}}$ as the final result.

Comment: I believe the factor of $1/2$ applies to both terms.  We can check this, as you suggest, by considering the simplest possible case: the one-dimensional standard Normal distribution where $C=(1)$ and $\bar w=(0).$  Letting $A=(1)$ reduces the integral to the expectation of *one-half* the square, which evaluates to $1/2 = \operatorname{Tr}(CA)/2.$  Thus the factor of $1/2$ *must* be in there.  Assume its absence in your reference is a typographical error.

Answer (score 4):

The solution posted by whuber gets at this idea but I wanted to make the approach more explicitly use the trace operator, use:

$$\mathbb{E}(u^TAu) = \mathbb{E}(tr(u^TAu)).$$
Note that the quadratic form inside the expectation is a scalar and trace of a scalar is the same scalar. Next use cyclic swap property of the trace operator:

$$\mathbb{E}(tr(u^TAu))= \mathbb{E}(tr(uu^TA)).$$

Now note that $A$ is a constant so you can factor that out:

$$ \mathbb{E}(tr(uu^TA))=tr(\mathbb{E}(uu^TA)).$$
Once more step:
$$tr(\mathbb{E}(uu^TA))= tr(\mathbb{E}(uu^T)A)$$

Next consider that by definition of the covariance matrix of a multivariate Gaussian:
$$ \mathbb{E}(uu^T) = C.$$

Stitch all of this together and you've got the result.

Comment: This is *almost* right: you forgot to subtract the means in the definition of $C.$

Comment: @whuber I am using the OP's notation where $u=w-\bar{w}$ where $\bar{w}$ is the mean of the original multivariate normal. The mean vectors after subtraction should be 0 vectors. Did I misunderstand your comment? Or maybe the OP's notation?

Comment: I did notice that I had some typos w/the trace operator and once missed inclusion altogether. I think the typos are removed now but let me know if you catch one

Comment: Thank you for the explanation--I hadn't made the connection with the OP's notation for residuals.